# How to deploy initial default preferences?

Tags: maui

I have a MAUI application, and I would like to incluid some default settings, so when I install the application, if I would go to the settings page, I would like to see this default settings.

I know could include a xml file or some file with initial configuration and initialize this settings on startup, but I would like to know if there are better options.

Perhaps using Preference.Default() method, but I think this option doesn't allow default settings when I deploy the application.

So in summary, I would like to know how to include a default settings with the application.

Thanks.

Comment: The function for getting has default value. From the docs: Preferences.Default.Get("age", -1);

Comment: You could refer to [Get preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/preferences?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=ios#get-preferences)